# Not able to start android L emulator API level 21 arm-evbi-va image

Tags: android, emulation

I m not able to start android L emulator , the emulator is stucked in the black screen.I have checked the Use host GPU option while creating the AVD. 
[image: Here is the screenshot of my logcat]

Comment: Just tossing this out there. But I had that happen when I started a vm in one display and then later tried to start it from another display. (I use my laptop with an external display).

Answer (score 0):

**Create AVD Following Formate and  Start AVD  For TV**

Name :MyAVD

Device: Nexus S (4.0 480*800 hdpi)

Target :Android L(Prieview)

CPU/ABI : Android TV ARM

Keyboard - Hardware Keyboard Present

Skin- WXGA720

RAM-343

VM-Heap -32

internal storage 512mb

sdcard size-512mb

Emulation option-USE Host GPU

for more detail please post ur AVD detail..